# What is the best way to perform query by ID or instead get all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to do a query filter but I don't want to repeat code. I would like to do it in one simple query, the simplest possible.

**Technology**

SQL Server v18

**The Acceptance Criteria**

Get by ID if the ID has a value (one single record in this case) OR IF ID = NULL then GET ALL

I've been trying with AND, ORs, IS NOT NULL, etc. But I would like to get the records in a simplest query.

Currently this is my query:

```
DECLARE @EventLogId int = null
SET @EventLogId = NULL

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT 
    EL.EventLogId,
    EL.EventLogDateTime,
    EL.Username,
    EL.EventLogTypeId,
    EL.ActionTypeId,
    EL.ProfessionalId,
    EL.BioId,
    EL.[Message],
    EL.ExceptionMessage,
    EL.StackTrace,
    ELTypes.[Name] AS EventLogTypeName,
    ATypes.[Name] AS ActionTypeName
FROM 
    dbo.EventLog EL
INNER JOIN 
    EventLogType ELTypes ON ELTypes.Id = EL.EventLogTypeId
INNER JOIN 
    ActionTypes ATypes ON ATypes.ActionTypeId = EL.ActionTypeId
WHERE 
    EL.EventLogId = @EventLogId 
    AND NOT(EL.EventLogId IS NULL)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"MSSQL Server v18"* Version 18 isn't out yet; we only *just* got version 16 (SQL Server 2022) last month.

Comment: There is **NO** SQL Server 18 version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 - take your pick ....

Comment: maybe v18 is about the engine?

Comment: `AND NOT(EL.EventLogId IS NULL)` why not the more traditional `EL.EventLogId IS NOT NULL`? Though you have already defined that `EL.EventLogId` *cannot* be `NULL` with your clause `EL.EventLogId = @EventLogId `, so it's actually redundant.

Comment: As I stated, the latest release is version 16, @GeorgeMenoutis . I don't imagine Version 18 to be out until 2026 at the earliest.

Comment: @Larnu Your reply shows my joke was rather...unsuccessful

Comment: When in doubt ... SELECT @@version

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis exactly it's the engine, not the IDE version, but whatever it is it's just a reference

Comment: @Larnu check the acceptance criteria, if parameter has value get a record if parameter null get all. Nobody is reading the acceptance criteria.

Comment: But you're checking the *column* not the parameter. When you check a scalar value against another with operators like `=`, `>`, `<`, etc, you implicit filter out `NULL` values as anything compared against `NULL` returns UNKNOWN. As such, in your attempt, the clause `NOT(EL.EventLogId IS NULL)` doesn't achieve anything, as you already know it's not `NULL` because of the clause `EL.EventLogId = @EventLogId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another option ... `coalesce()`

```
WHERE  EL.EventLogId = coalesce(@EventLogId,EL.EventLogId)
```

Comment: Nice one-liner, though I'd avoid it in any nontrivial query since it gives off nonSARGable vibes.

Answer (score 4):

A common pattern for this in SQL Server is

```
SELECT 
    EL.EventLogId,
    EL.EventLogDateTime,
    EL.Username,
    EL.EventLogTypeId,
    EL.ActionTypeId,
    EL.ProfessionalId,
    EL.BioId,
    EL.[Message],
    EL.ExceptionMessage,
    EL.StackTrace,
    ELTypes.[Name] AS EventLogTypeName,
    ATypes.[Name] AS ActionTypeName
FROM 
    dbo.EventLog EL
INNER JOIN 
    EventLogType ELTypes ON ELTypes.Id = EL.EventLogTypeId
INNER JOIN 
    ActionTypes ATypes ON ATypes.ActionTypeId = EL.ActionTypeId
WHERE 
    EL.EventLogId = @EventLogId OR @EventLogId IS NULL 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` prevents SQL Server from using the same plan for both cases, which would be bad.

Comment: Nice extra tidbit there with option recompile

Comment: Of course Recompile means a compilation occurs on every execution, so evaluate the complexity of the query and / or how frequently it executes; for frequently executing queries or large compilation times it may be better to have 2 versions either dsql or a wrapper proc.

Comment: I keep thinking that the amount of oldtimers this run-of-the-mill question has gathered is due to the hilarity of v18.

Answer (score 3):

You're so close:

```
WHERE 
    EL.EventLogId = @EventLogId 
    OR @EventLogId IS NULL
```

This problem is called "dynamic search conditions". The alternative is dynamic sql. When you have some time, read [Erland Sommarskog's excellent article](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) about this.